# How to tell which query is the data fetched from in a MySQL statement with UNION

Tags: mysql, union

the table

```
id    string
------------
1     aaa
2     bbb
3     ccc
4     ddd
```

the query

```
(SELECT string FROM table WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)    /* num_row = 1 */
UNION
(SELECT string FROM table WHERE id < 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)   /* null */
UNION
(SELECT string FROM table WHERE id > 4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)    /* null */
UNION
(SELECT string FROM table WHERE id < 4 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)   /* num_row = 2 */
```

The query above will return `2 rows` since there are no id=5 and id=0.

How can I tell which queries are these 2 rows fetched from?

that is, `num_row = 1` from `1st SELECT`, and `num_row = 2` from `4th SELECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a second column to indicate from where the data comes from

```
(SELECT string, '1st query' as from_where FROM table WHERE ...)
UNION
(SELECT string, '2nd query' as from_whereFROM table WHERE ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
(SELECT 1, string FROM table WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)   
UNION
(SELECT 2, string FROM table WHERE id < 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)  
UNION
(SELECT 3, string FROM table WHERE id > 4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)   
UNION
(SELECT 4, string FROM table WHERE id < 4 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment by mistake. (Comment was "the meaning of `UNION` (vs `UNION ALL`) will be lost here"). I agree though that the OP should be responsible for it and this is probably what they were looking for anyway - I was merely pointing out the caveat :)

Comment: thanks Marco. the returned array is something like [1]=>1, [2]=>4. on the first glance of this array, I got a bit confused, tho it is perfectly right. I think using `as` makes it better understanding like @juergen suggested. `[from_where]=>'1st query', [from_where]=>'4th query'` along with other data inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra constant column with a common alias:

```
(SELECT string, 'query_1' as query_num FROM table WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)    
UNION
(SELECT string, 'query_2' as query_num FROM table WHERE id < 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT string, 'query_3' as query_num FROM table WHERE id > 4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)    
UNION
(SELECT string, 'query_4' as query_num FROM table WHERE id < 4 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try (inelegant as it is):

(SELECT '1', string FROM table WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)    /* num_row = 1 */
UNION
(SELECT '2', string FROM table WHERE id < 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)   /* null */
UNION
(SELECT '3', string FROM table WHERE id > 4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)    /* null */
UNION
(SELECT '4', string FROM table WHERE id < 4 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)   /* num_row = 2